# ERROR ITMS-90730ITMS Failed to Upload IPA in Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, ipa, application-loader

I want to upload ipa to AppStore.

I failed to upload the AppStore, 
I tried it with the Apple method, but it still didn't work.  System 10.14.4, xcode10.2.1.

ERROR ITMS-90730: "Found Metal shader source code. The metal library file, 'Payload/xxx.app/default.metallib', contains source code or debugging information intended only for development. To resolve this issue, set the “Produce debugging information” build setting in Xcode to “No” and upload your app again. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/tools_profiling_and_debugging/developing_shaders_and_resolving_shader_issues_with_the_shader_debugger)."

God, I just want to upload successfully.

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggested that you do?

Comment: did you try to  set the “Produce debugging information” build setting in Xcode to “No” and upload your app again ?

Comment: @Akber Iqbal   I tried but it didn't work

Comment: I have solved this bug, my custom framework has a problem, I deleted it and I can upload now.